# 60 amp 240 volt Backyard sub-panel

Tags: electrical

1. What wire size do I need to run to install a 240 volt-60amp sub-panel 250' from the 100 amp main panel in the garage?
2. Direct burial or conduit or both?

Comment: You need #6Cu or #4Al for safety, but that says nothing about voltage drop.  How much power do you intend to *actually draw* from it on a regular basis?  Also how deep do you want to trench this, 26", 20",  or 8" and pay more for the conduit?

Comment: Are your conditions conducive to trenching?  What is this subpanel powering, for that matter?